# Operator overloading showing irregular behaviour in output

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual-functions, overriding, comparison-operators

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class base
{
public:
  virtual bool operator ==( const base& other ) =0;
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
  bool operator ==( const base& other ) { return false; }
  bool operator ==( const derived& other ) { return true; }
};


int main()
{
  base* a = new derived;
  base* b = a;
  std::cout << ( *a == *b ) << std::endl;
  cout<< (dynamic_cast< base*>(b) == dynamic_cast< base*>(a));

}
```

`std::cout << ( *a == *b ) << std::endl;` will call `Derived::operator==( const base& other )`, but why is `cout << (dynamic_cast<base*>(b) == dynamic_cast<base*>(a));` giving 1 in the output?

Comment: But why isnt it calling any overloaded operator == ??

Comment: You're comparing pointers.

Comment: Indeed. I think you didn't intend this, but in addition to introducing the dynamic cast, you have also removed the dereferencing in the second version.

Comment: You mean to say that using dynamic cast will not need to call the operator overloading.

Comment: @pushE No, you just forgot a `*` before the `dynamic_cast`, of course the *pointers* are the same and will thus compare equal.

Comment: @jogojapan That is an answer and not a comment.

Comment: @ChristianRau Really? I am not quite sure what was intended... If the missing `*` is an accident, the question gets a totally different meaning.

Comment: @jogojapan If it wasn't intended, you comment is a perfectly correct answer. If it was intended, then the question is rubbish anyway, since both `*a` and `*b` have static type `base` and dynamic type `derived` and point to the same object, so I don't know what on earth he would want to test with this code other than the his compiler knows how `=` and `==` works on pointers.

Comment: @ChristianRau Right... I just feel there should be further clarification before this question is ready to be answered. But feel free to post an answer. I won't mind.

Comment: @ChristianRau This is the only question,I am confused that why isnt the compiler calling the overloaded func == rather than direcly comparing and passing the result as true

Comment: @pushE **Because you're invoking it on pointers!** What should `a == b` result in, if not `true` (hint: **no stars!**)? You are just casting and comparing both pointers and **not** the objects they point to, so those operator overloads don't even come into play here. Try `*dynamic_cast< base*>(b) == *dynamic_cast< base*>(a)` (**mind the stars!**) and see what happens.

Comment: You **do** realize that `derived::operator ==( const derived& other )` has a **different signature** and thus **doesn't override** `base::operator ==( const base& other )`, don't you?